# web integrated mobile application

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans, mobile

i want to built an application, using the netbeans mobile application software(ME), which gets data from a website and then display it on the screen may be in a text box.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check out some of the tutorials on this site:

http://www.netbeans.org/kb/trails/mobility.html